# SVG pie chart (donut) slice selection via javascript, html, css

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, pie-chart

I have my css hover working correctly and I can hard code the css class and get the html to use .active but I cannot get my pie slices to switch to active state upon click.  Additionally, after I get this working, I want to be able to select multiple pie slices and capture the id's.  I'm not that great with javascript so... be gentle with me :)
page header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>

</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

/* this is for selecting and deselecting svg pie pieces 
$('group_path').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}); */

/* This is the javascript to select pie pieces */
// Get the container element
var group_pathContainer = document.getElementById("4");
var group_paths = group_pathContainer.querySelectorAll(".group_path");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < group_paths.length; i++) {
  group_paths[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var current = e.currentTarget;
    // toggle active class to the current/clicked button
    current.classList.toggle('active');
    getActive();
  });
}

// list all active pie segemnts
function getActive(){
  let actives = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
  let idArray = [];
  actives.forEach(function(el,i){
    let id = el.id;
    idArray.push(id)
  })
  console.log(idArray)
}

</script>
```

svg

```
 <svg viewBox='-1 -1 2 2' style='transform: scale(1.0); rotate(-90deg)';>
                <g id="4" >
                      <g id="4.01" class="active" fill='rgb(84,161,229)' >
                      <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M 1.000000 0.000000 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.873262 0.487250 L 0 0 '></path>
                      <text d='M 1.000000 0.000000 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.873262 0.487250 L 0 0 ' fill="none" x="0.9">Project</text>
                      </g>
                       <g id="4.02" class="active" fill='rgb(242,162,84)'>
                      <path  stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M 0.873262 0.487250 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.147119 0.989119 L 0 0 '></path>
                      </g>
                       <g id="4.03" class="group_path" fill='rgb(237,110,133)' >
                    <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.147119 0.989119 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.689114 0.724653 L 0 0 '></path>
                    </g>
                       <g id="4.04" class="group_path" fill='rgb(173,205,225)' >
                    <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.689114 0.724653 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.915241 0.402907 L 0 0 '></path>
                    </g>
                       <g id="4.05" class="group_path" fill='rgb(187,221,147)' >
                    <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.915241 0.402907 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.946085 0.323917 L 0 0 '></path>
                    </g>
                       <g id="4.06" class="group_path" fill='rgb(238,158,155)' >
                    <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.946085 0.323917 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.978581 -0.205863 L 0 0 '></path>
                    </g>
                       <g id="4.07" class="group_path active" fill='rgb(84,161,229)' >
                    <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.978581 -0.205863 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.879316 -0.476238 L 0 0 '></path>
                    </g>
                       <g id="4.08" class="group_path" fill='rgb(108,190,191)'>
                   <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.879316 -0.476238 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.527846 -0.849340 L 0 0 '></path>
                   </g>
                       <g id="4.09" class="group_path" fill='rgb(242,162,84)' >
                    <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.527846 -0.849340 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.056518 -0.998402 L 0 0 '></path>
                    </g>
                       <g id="4.10" class="group_path" fill='rgb(237,110,133)'>
                    <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M 0.056518 -0.998402 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.543760 -0.839241 L 0 0 '></path>
                    </g>
                       <g id="4.11" class="group_path" fill='rgb(173,205,225)'>
                    <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M 0.543760 -0.839241 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.711535 -0.702650 L 0 0 '></path>
                    </g>
                       <g id="4.12" class="group_path" fill='rgb(187,221,147)'>
                    <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M 0.711535 -0.702650 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.724653 -0.689114 L 0 0 '></path>
                    </g>
                       <g id="4.13" class="group_path" fill='rgb(42,228,229)'>
                    <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.00625px' d='M 0.724653 -0.689114 A 1 1 0 0 1 1.000000 -0.000000 L 0 0 '></path>
                    </g>                      
                    <circle fill='#fff' cx='0' cy='0' r='0.80'/>
                </g>
```

css

```
.group_path:hover{
 /* fill: purple; */
  transform: scale(.95, .95);
}
.group_path.active { 
  fill: purple;
  transform: scale(.92, .92);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use ancient Javascript and DOM methods with modern SVG elements? The code had basicly worked in 2011, now more than ten years later JS and DOM methods have evolved a lot. Apart from that, notice, that white-space characters are not a part of the classname.

Comment: The only reason is my ignorance.  I don’t do much JavaScript. Most of my experience has been  some Jquery for hidden containers toggling.

Comment: @No need for jquery – but it should't do any harm either. Your `<script>` element should be placed at the bottom of your html (so before the closing `</body>` tag ( so not in the <head>.

Comment: That was it!!!  Thank you.  I thought all scripts went on top in the header.  It's probably my php background that made me think that way!  Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your active class doesn't have any effect since your path's fill attribute has a higher specificity.
change you css like so:

```
.active path{ 
  fill: purple;
  transform: scale(.92, .92);
}
```

To set a pi segment active or non-active you could use a `classList.toggle()` approach:

```js
/* This is the javascript to select pie pieces */
// Get the container element
var group_pathContainer = document.getElementById("4");
var group_paths = group_pathContainer.querySelectorAll(".group_path");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < group_paths.length; i++) {
  group_paths[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var current = e.currentTarget;
    // toggle active class to the current/clicked button
    current.classList.toggle('active');
    getActive();
  });
}

// list all active pie segemnts
function getActive(){
  let actives = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
  let idArray = [];
  actives.forEach(function(el,i){
    let id = el.id;
    idArray.push(id)
  })
  console.log(idArray)
}
```

```css
svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:20em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}


.active path{ 
  fill: purple;
  transform: scale(.92, .92);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='-1 -1 2 2' style='transform: scale(1.0); rotate(-90deg)' >
  <g id="4">
    <g id="4.01" class="group_path">
      <path fill='rgb(84,161,229)' stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M 1.000000 0.000000 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.873262 0.487250 L 0 0 '></path>
      <text d='M 1.000000 0.000000 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.873262 0.487250 L 0 0 ' fill="none" x="0.9">Project</text>
    </g>
    <g id="4.02" class="group_path">
      <path fill='rgb(242,162,84)' stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M 0.873262 0.487250 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.147119 0.989119 L 0 0 '></path>
    </g>
    <g id="4.03" class="group_path">
      <path fill='rgb(237,110,133)' stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.147119 0.989119 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.689114 0.724653 L 0 0 '></path>
    </g>
    <g id="4.04" class="group_path">
      <path fill='rgb(173,205,225)' stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.689114 0.724653 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.915241 0.402907 L 0 0 '></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

### Example 2: fill defined by group

```js
/* This is the javascript to select pie pieces */
// Get the container element
var group_pathContainer = document.getElementById("4");
var group_paths = group_pathContainer.querySelectorAll(".group_path");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < group_paths.length; i++) {
  group_paths[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var current = e.currentTarget;
    // toggle active class to the current/clicked button
    current.classList.toggle('active');
    getActive();
  });
}

// list all active pie segemnts
function getActive(){
  let actives = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
  let idArray = [];
  actives.forEach(function(el,i){
    let id = el.id;
    idArray.push(id)
  })
  console.log(idArray)
}
```

```css
svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:20em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}


.group_path.active { 
  fill: purple;
  transform: scale(.92, .92);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='-1 -1 2 2' style='transform: scale(1.0); rotate(-90deg)' >
  <g id="4">
    <g id="4.01" class="group_path" fill='rgb(84,161,229)'>
      <path stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M 1.000000 0.000000 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.873262 0.487250 L 0 0 '></path>
      <text d='M 1.000000 0.000000 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.873262 0.487250 L 0 0 ' fill="none" x="0.9">Project</text>
    </g>
    <g id="4.02" class="group_path" fill='rgb(242,162,84)'>
      <path  stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M 0.873262 0.487250 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.147119 0.989119 L 0 0 '></path>
    </g>
    <g id="4.03" class="group_path" fill='rgb(237,110,133)'>
      <path  stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.147119 0.989119 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.689114 0.724653 L 0 0 '></path>
    </g>
    <g id="4.04" class="group_path" fill='rgb(173,205,225)'>
      <path  stroke='white' stroke-width='.0125px' d='M -0.689114 0.724653 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.915241 0.402907 L 0 0 '></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you!  I modified the svg to move the fill to the group instead of the path and it worked but I still cannot get the toggle to switch classes in the group tag.  When I manually change the class the css and fill work.  But I made my css - .active group_path{

Comment: Nothing I do selects anything with the mouse.  I can only hard code the elements with the class.  Do I have to download some js info/library?  I thought coding it directly into the script on the html page alleviated that need.

Comment: @Vets: no need for a library. I've added a new example .  It should be `.group_path.active {...}` since .group_path and .active are on the same level

Comment: Both of your examples work exactly how I would like mine to work but my selecting doesn't occur.  Am I missing a js tag?  `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> ` is how I wrap the js code and ` </script>` is how i end it.  I'm confused why Nothing selects.  What else could be not allowing selections but allowing hard coded classes to work?  Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @Vets: you could add a new snippet to your answer so I could check your current code

Comment: Updated the snippet.  I cannot select a pie slice but hover works.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples that @herrstrietzel provided work.

I had my javascript tags in the wrong location (in the header).  Once I moved them to just above `</body>` near the bottom of the page everything worked perfect!

Comment: glad it worked. You could then accept tag the answer as accepted ;)